# Проблема Фарш-view

Tags: android, view

День Добрый. Только начал учиться по книги для разработки приложений под Андроид. Возник вопрос. В LinearLayout, для деления места (как я понял ) используется layout::weight, НО в ConstraintLayout нет layout::weight. Как быть? Ибо получается вот такой треш. Картинка и текст должны быть отдельно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну... Вариант замены констрэинта на линеар рассматриваете?

Comment: Как это возможно? В activity_main.xml провожу замену (</RelativeLayout> <android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"), а в итоге выдает ошибку - отсутствует класс!

Comment: Да, такого класса в этом пакете нет. Пишите просто `<LinearLayout>`

Comment: Я не могу тогда дальше работать. https://imgur.com/URaCKQG

Comment: Добавьте разметку кодом в вопрос. Надо её править. Вообще лучше в xml работать и не юзать предпросмотрорщик если не умеете в xml макет делать

Comment: в LinearLayout обязательно нужно указать оринтецию, так как у вас более одного елемента